# How to change frame size of ABCalendarPicker view and customise date cell

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar

For one of my project I'm using **ABCalendarPicker** but I don't know how to change the height of the calendar.

Im using following code for that:

```
self.calendarPicker = [[ABCalendarPicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
self.calendarPicker.swipeNavigationEnabled = NO;
self.calendarPicker.bottomExpanding = YES;
[self.calendarPicker setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.calendarPicker];
```

But its not changing the height of the view. Also I noticed that Its changing view only in square mode. Means If I change width from **320 to 300** then height will change as per width.

1. So, how to make Calendar size 320X280?
2. Also how to customise the cell that showing dates? I want to add image on particular date.
3. Call back when user tap on particular date.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the first question i.e. **How to make Calendar size 320X280?**

Change value for `buttonHeight` variable in `ABCalendarPicker.m` class, in following method

`- (void)updateButtonsForProvider:(id<ABCalendarPickerDateProviderProtocol>)provider andState:(ABCalendarPickerState)state ;`

Default height is the same as width.(`CGFloat buttonHeight = buttonWidth`).

---

Answer for the last question i.e **"Call back when user tap on particular date"**

There are two delegate methods that will be fired when user tap on particular date cell. You can do in that methods whatever you want.

```
- (BOOL)calendarPicker:(ABCalendarPicker*)calendarPicker
       shoudSelectDate:(NSDate*)date
             withState:(ABCalendarPickerState)state ;

- (void)calendarPicker:(ABCalendarPicker*)calendarPicker
          dateSelected:(NSDate*)date
             withState:(ABCalendarPickerState)state ;
```

Now waiting for the answer of second question. Will edit if I will be success my self.